# Reload UITableView after changing its underlying data in a different View Controller in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a table view with Wishlist items. when taping on a row I present a new view with detailed information about an item (through did select row at index path) the view also gives you a possibility to edit data. I was able to save the changes, but the table view does not update.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !itemsTable.isEditing {
        let item = self.itemsArray[indexPath.row]
        let detailVC = DetailedVC()
        detailVC.item = item
        itemsTable.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

this is how I call a pop up view controller

```
        var item: WishlistItem?

        @objc func editButtonPressed() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = item
        entity?.name = itemName.text
        entity?.link = itemLink.text
        entity?.price = itemPrice.text
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
     }
```

and this is a piece of code which is responsible for saving changes

I have tried calling reloaddata from detailedVC, but it does not seem to work.
Any thoughts on how to do it correctly?
also will be thankful for any feedback

Comment: how  you tried calling reloaddata from detailedVC?

Comment: @jawadAli I created an instance of a view containing table view. (let f  = firstView()->f.tableView.reloadData())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the table View with the new content you have to call this method:
`tableView.reloadData()`

There are two ways of updating the tableView when making changes inside another View Controller.

> First: Initialise or pass in the reference to the tableView to the new view controller. Then you are able to call `tableView.reloadData()`out of your second VC as soon as you made the changes.

However the second solution is the one you should aim for.

> Second: Use the **Delegate Design Pattern** to inform the first View Controller as soon as the second View Controller will Disappear or the changes are made:

```swift
protocol SubviewDelegate {
    func subviewWillClose()
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SubviewDelegate?

    override viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        delegate?.subviewWillClose()
    }

}
```

Now, your first View Controller must conform to the SubviewDelegate Protocol and implement the method `subviewWillClose`:

```swift
extension FirstVC: SubviewDelegate {

    func subviewWillClose() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

**And don't forget to setup the delegate property with an instance of the FirstVC Class, so that its not nil!**

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful. Wish you all the best.

Comment: @Vale I am glad that I could help you. Happy coding!